# Signing launch4j generated exe corrupts it

Tags: java, exe, sign, launch4j

I generated an executable jar file through Eclipse (it's a GUI application, and does not require a console), then put it through launch4j to generate an exe file for windows.
This all works well and as intended (the program still runs as it should), but virus total shows a false positive, and after a quick search I found out that signing my executable is a way to fix this.

After multiple attempts at signing my jar, using the following commands as attempts:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Launch4j\sign4j\sign4j.exe" java -jar jsign-2.1.jar --alias 'example.org' --keystore 'keystore.pfx' --storepass 'pass' --storetype PKCS12 'progam.exe'

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Launch4j\sign4j\sign4j.exe" -s keyfile.pfx -a "(codesign_1091_es_sw_kpsc)" --storepass pass --storetype pkcs12 -n Client -u https://www.example.org program.exe

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Launch4j\sign4j\sign4j.exe" --verbose signtool.exe sign /fd SHA256 /f keyfile.pfx /p pass /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll my_signed.exe
```

None of these seemed to work, the first attempt would output the help message from sign4j.exe (as if no arguments were provided).
2nd attempt will output:

```
Making temporary file
'"keyfile.pfx"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'"keyfile.pfx"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

and the third attempt (after setting up windows 10 sdk for signtool.exe)
will only say "Could not open file" (not even specifying which file).

I then came across some documentation on the sign4j github with some example code, where you can import the library and sign the exe through a java file. So I gave this a shot, and put together the following script:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;

import net.jsign.KeyStoreUtils;
import net.jsign.PESigner;
import net.jsign.pe.PEFile;

public class Sign4j {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyStore keystore;
        try {
            keystore = KeyStoreUtils.load(new File("keystore.pfx"), "PKCS12", "pass", null);

            PESigner signer;
            try {
                signer = new PESigner(keystore, "RuneRealm.org", "vnSsmwj4TYeurUYQ");

                signer.withProgramName("Client")
                   .withProgramURL("https://www.example.org")
                   .withTimestamping(true)
                   .withTimestampingAutority("http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode");

                try {
                    signer.sign(new PEFile(new File("Program.exe")));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (KeyStoreException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And at last, it worked! Or so it seems..
There was no output generated and the program was changed, (last change date was updated), now I put it through virustotal again and the false postives were gone. Feeling very happy with myself I attempted to run the program, but it would popup the error:

```
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile (path to my signed exe)
```

At this point I have no idea where to go from here? I have been searching for other alternatives to signing an exe, and nearly all my search results point to a command used for signing similar to one of my 3 attempts (of which none worked).

The closest I came was using the java script, but since the only resolution I seem to read every where is that "signing with jsign will avoid corruption" and that did not work I am not sure how to proceed.

I have looked in to alternatives for launch4j, as jar2exe for example. Which wasn't even able to generate a working exe, the exe generated through launch4j works very well and even kept the system tray and additional libraries support (these libraries were already packed inside the executable jar)

Answer (score 0):

A little late for this, but I was able to get it to work with the first option without using the single quotes:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Launch4j\sign4j\sign4j.exe" java -jar jsign-3.1.jar --alias example.org --keystore keystore.pfx --storepass pass --storetype PKCS12 progam.exe
```